# Existence of proper invariant subspaces for compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Around 1950, J. von Neumann proved the existence of proper invariant subspaces for compact operators in a Hilbert space. Does anyone know a reference for a simplified proof of this fact?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomonosov%27s_invariant_subspace_theorem

Comment: In the introduction to "Invariant Subspaces of Completely Continuous Operators" (Annals of Mathematics, vol. 60, no. 2, 1954, pp. 345–50, https://doi.org/10.2307/1969637) Aronszajn and Smith say that "some years ago," von Neumann informed Aronszajn that he had proved this result "in the early thirties" but that it was never published.  (In the linked paper, Aronszajn and Smith prove the result for compact operators on arbitrary Banach spaces.)